# Does each channel create a different blokchcain in hyperledger-fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In hyperledger fabric, we can have multiple state databases corresponding to each channel the node has joined. Do we also have multiple blockchains corresponding to each channel for a node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in Fabric there is only one ledger per channel. Ledger in Fabric contains two components. One is called the **world state** which stores the latest value of the keys. Another one is called **blockchain** which stores all the transaction log that leads to the world state. So back to your question, there should be one state databases (world state) and blockchain per channel. Each peer in the channel hold a copy of the ledger and thus should have a consistent view on the world state within the channel.

For more information, you may refer to the following:

1. Docs on Ledger 
   https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ledger/ledger.html

Comment: Thanks Issac. It sound very inefficient for certain use cases. Imagine that A buys an asset on a channel x from B. Now A wants to sell it to C on a different channel y. There are different channels to keep the transactions private. Not sure how can this be implemented using fabric.